# How can I write a for loop with (a < b < c) under one statement?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a for loop that looks like this.

```
int a = 3;
int b;
int c = 20;
for ( a = 1; a < b < c; ++a )
```

But the program doesn't work like this. How am i suppose to correctly state that stament in the middle a < b < c?

Comment: is there any and statement that i can use in the loop?

Answer (score 8):

Change `a < b < c` to `a < b && b < c`

#### Explanation

The reason is that, `<` is evaluated from left-to-right, so your statement is evaluated like this:

```
a < b < c  -->  (a < b) < c
```

`(a < b)` is a boolean value (0 or 1) and `c` is being compared to that value.

If you have both `a < b` and `b < c`, since `<` is [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), you would know that the mathematical `a < b < c` holds.

*Note*: Taking a look at the [C operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), you can see that in the expression `a < b && b < c`, first `a < b` and `b < c` are evaluated, then the results are "and"ed.

#### Your example

In your example, since `b` is not set, `a < b` is not known, but whether it is 0 or 1, it is definitely smaller than `c` which is 20. So basically you've got an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Im just dumb I had that in mind but my program didnt work because I didnt do <=

Comment: Well `a <= b <= c` wouldn't work as you expected either. You have no choice but to break the statement in two. If you learn that `<` (and similar operators) are "binary" operators, which means they act on 2 values and the result is a boolean, you would understand it completely.